# Trying to figure out how function(i) works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in the process of trying to understand the reasons behind why certain things work. In the code below it animates 3 objects 1 at a time when I put in function(i) and then ().delay(i*1000). How does adding an argument "i"  go from animating everything to one at a time?

```
       <div class="dotMarker">
           <div class="glowMarker"></div>
           <div class="glowDot"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="dotMarker">
           <div class="glowMarker"></div>
           <div class="glowDot"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="dotMarker">
           <div class="glowMarker"></div>
           <div class="glowDot"></div>
       </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dotMarker').each(function(i){
        $(this).delay(i*1000).animate( {opacity: 1, top:'+=50px'}, '2000', function(){
            $(this).children('.glowDot').delay(100).animate( {opacity: 1, width: "+=25px"}, '2000');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) documentation?

Comment: The `i` passed from the `$(...).each()` or `$.each(myArray,...)` method references the index of each item in the array.

Comment: `$('.dotMarker').each` calls the provided function once for every element in the collection.  It passes that function the index of the element in the set and the element itself (you can actually do `$('.dotMarker').each(function(i, v){`).  See http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Thank you everyone. For some reason I just thought .each() grabbed content, instead of actually creating a loop.

Comment: I see about 1/2 dozen links here to the same docs ....  read the manual first before asking here. Saves all of us time. In fact spend some time familiarizing yourself with the API as there are examples for every method in the jQuery API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter in the function passed to `.each()` is given a value starting at 0 and counting up for each of the elements passed to `.each()`.

So for the first element you will be calling

```
$(this).delay(0 * 1000)...  = $(this).delay(0)...
```

For the second element

```
$(this).delay(1 * 1000)...  = $(this).delay(1000)...
```

For the third

```
$(this).delay(2 * 1000)...  = $(this).delay(2000)...
```

And so on, staggering the animations on the elements by 1 second each.